# Google Maps Java Client - GeocodingApi.reverseGeocode not returning results

Tags: java, google-maps

all.

I'm using Java Client for Google Maps Services (https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java) to have some simple address and distance functionality in my app.

I'm using Gradle to build the project, here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {   
    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.2.7'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.25'
}
```

When I use the URL request in the browser, everything works fine:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-3.775657,-38.456086&key=APP_KEY

This returns the json:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Regents Drive",
               "short_name" : "Regents Dr",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Midtown",
               "short_name" : "Midtown",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Atlanta",
               "short_name" : "Atlanta",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Fulton County",
               "short_name" : "Fulton County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Georgia",
               "short_name" : "GA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Estados Unidos",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "30318",
               "short_name" : "30318",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Regents Dr, Atlanta, GA 30318, EUA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 33.7738168,
                  "lng" : -84.4027023
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.773736,
                  "lng" : -84.4027736
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 33.7737764,
               "lng" : -84.402738
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 33.7751253802915,
                  "lng" : -84.40138896970851
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.7724274197085,
                  "lng" : -84.40408693029151
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJo4ce6I4E9YgR7lIy86g_9qg",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Georgia Tech",
               "short_name" : "Georgia Tech",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Atlanta",
               "short_name" : "Atlanta",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Fulton County",
               "short_name" : "Fulton County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Georgia",
               "short_name" : "GA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Estados Unidos",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Georgia Tech, Atlanta, GA, EUA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 33.7815729,
                  "lng" : -84.39036369999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.7712771,
                  "lng" : -84.40759419999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 33.7784626,
               "lng" : -84.3988806
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 33.7815729,
                  "lng" : -84.39036369999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.7712771,
                  "lng" : -84.40759419999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJbw3_E4oE9YgR9yiVCsbTgyY",
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Midtown Atlanta",
               "short_name" : "Midtown Atlanta",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Atlanta",
               "short_name" : "Atlanta",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Condado de Fulton",
               "short_name" : "Condado de Fulton",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Geórgia",
               "short_name" : "GA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Estados Unidos",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Midtown Atlanta, Atlanta, GA, EUA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 33.8065291,
                  "lng" : -84.3646146
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.7712281,
                  "lng" : -84.41529749999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 33.7833019,
               "lng" : -84.3828403
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 33.8065291,
                  "lng" : -84.3646146
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.7712281,
                  "lng" : -84.41529749999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ1fsiOmsE9YgRKGR8OxRmepQ",
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Atlanta",
               "short_name" : "Atlanta",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Condado de Fulton",
               "short_name" : "Condado de Fulton",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Geórgia",
               "short_name" : "GA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Estados Unidos",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Atlanta, GA, EUA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 33.8876179,
                  "lng" : -84.289389
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.6478079,
                  "lng" : -84.5518189
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 33.7489954,
               "lng" : -84.3879824
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 33.8876179,
                  "lng" : -84.289389
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.6478079,
                  "lng" : -84.5518189
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJjQmTaV0E9YgRC2MLmS_e_mY",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "30313",
               "short_name" : "30313",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Atlanta",
               "short_name" : "Atlanta",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Condado de Fulton",
               "short_name" : "Condado de Fulton",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Geórgia",
               "short_name" : "GA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Estados Unidos",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Atlanta, GA 30313, EUA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 33.7815329,
                  "lng" : -84.38102889999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.743081,
                  "lng" : -84.40836689999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 33.7657549,
               "lng" : -84.39493999999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 33.7815329,
                  "lng" : -84.3898749
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.743081,
                  "lng" : -84.40836689999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJJQJalYEE9YgR8QEwdW22NnU",
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Condado de Fulton",
               "short_name" : "Condado de Fulton",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Geórgia",
               "short_name" : "GA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Estados Unidos",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Condado de Fulton, GA, EUA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.1862889,
                  "lng" : -84.097692
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.502412,
                  "lng" : -84.850713
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 33.8033965,
               "lng" : -84.3962535
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.1862889,
                  "lng" : -84.097692
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 33.502412,
                  "lng" : -84.850713
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ0dNnmHCr9YgRE8XXDotB0tc",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Atlanta-Sandy Springs-Marietta, GA",
               "short_name" : "Atlanta-Sandy Springs-Marietta, GA",
               "types" : [ "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Georgia",
               "short_name" : "GA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Estados Unidos",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Atlanta-Sandy Springs-Marietta, GA, GA, EUA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.617918,
                  "lng" : -83.505726
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 32.84464,
                  "lng" : -85.38647349999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 33.8498184,
               "lng" : -84.43827210000001
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.617918,
                  "lng" : -83.505726
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 32.84464,
                  "lng" : -85.38647349999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ_fZgxcoC9YgRrGCAOeFGG7s",
         "types" : [ "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Atlanta Metropolitan Area",
               "short_name" : "Atlanta Metropolitan Area",
               "types" : [ "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Georgia",
               "short_name" : "GA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Estados Unidos",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Atlanta Metropolitan Area, GA, EUA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.6179238,
                  "lng" : -83.26913379999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 32.84464,
                  "lng" : -85.3865809
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 33.8498184,
               "lng" : -84.43827210000001
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.6179238,
                  "lng" : -83.26913379999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 32.84464,
                  "lng" : -85.3865809
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJfSgTeBYB9YgReUv3J84hbQI",
         "types" : [ "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Geórgia",
               "short_name" : "GA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Estados Unidos",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Geórgia, EUA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.0006589,
                  "lng" : -80.751429
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 30.3555908,
                  "lng" : -85.60516490000001
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 32.1656221,
               "lng" : -82.9000751
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.0006589,
                  "lng" : -80.751429
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 30.3555908,
                  "lng" : -85.60516490000001
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJV4FfHcU28YgR5xBP7BC8hGY",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Estados Unidos",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Estados Unidos",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 71.5388001,
                  "lng" : -66.885417
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.7763,
                  "lng" : 170.5957
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.09024,
               "lng" : -95.712891
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 49.38,
                  "lng" : -66.94
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 25.82,
                  "lng" : -124.39
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJCzYy5IS16lQRQrfeQ5K5Oxw",
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

But when I try to do the same thing with the Java client, I get no results. My code:

```
public void loadAddress() throws ApiException, InterruptedException, IOException {
        LatLng location = new LatLng(latCoordinate, longCoordinate);

        GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey("<APP_KEY>").build();
        GeocodingApiRequest request = GeocodingApi.reverseGeocode(context, location);
        GeocodingResult[] results = request.await();

        int i = 0;
        System.out.println("Results length: " + results.length);
        for (GeocodingResult result : results) {
            System.out.println("Result " + (++i) + ": " +result.formattedAddress);
            System.out.println("Latitude: " + result.geometry.location.lat);
            System.out.println("Longitude: " + result.geometry.location.lng);
        }

    }
```

Console:

```
C:\Workspace\Java\GoogleAPITests>gradlew run
Task :run
Results length: 0
```

As you can see, request.await(); isn't returning expected values. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to be funny here, but where are your `latCoordinate` and `longCoordinate` being set? They're not arguments to this public method, so I assume they are set in scope somewhere. Maybe try a `println` prior to the location constructor call.

Comment: I'm ashamed and deserve to be punished. My constructor was empty. Thank you. :(
Please, Ops, erase this question and ban me from this site.